# He sleeps 10 hours a day VS He sleeps for 10 hours a day

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I have seen this sentence in a book:

> He sleeps 10 hours a day.

To be begin with, I thought this sentence needs preposition **'for'** like this:

> He sleeps **for** 10 hours a day

However I am wondering whether the sentence is possible without **'for'**.Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are grammatically correct. However there is a slight difference in the meaning of the two.
The first one:

> He sleeps 10 hours a day.

means that he sleeps a total of 10 hours in a day, not necessarily consecutively. He could be sleeping 8 hours at night and 2 hours afternoon.
Whereas the second one:

> He sleeps for 10 hours a day

implies that he sleeps for 10 hours consecutively, only one sleep a day.

Comment: I suspect unless you were specific about sleep being broken up most people would assume consecutively since that's the normal way people sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same as the preposition in this case does not give much difference.
Both are grammatically correct.
In my opinion:
He sleeps 10 hours a day —>He sleeps a total of 10 hours per day

He sleeps for 10 hours a day —>He sleeps 10 hours a day only at night, so this does not imply those long he sleeps for naps, etc.

However, I think that “He sleeps 10 hours a day “ is better.